# Can someone identify this 2 feet high plant?

Tags: identification

This has come up spontaneously in my parents garden.
Probably seeded by birds or grew from spilled bird-seed (it is right next to the bird-seeder).
The location is right on the border between Netherlands and Belgium, north-east of the city of Antwerpen.
(Yes, I know there is cannabis growing right next to it. That also grew spontaneously.)

It is about 2 feet high and 8 weeks old now. The largest leaves are about 4" long and the older leaves at the bottom of the main stem seem to loose the spiky points.
It is a single main stem that has much smaller branches starting about 1 foot of the ground.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've put your images into [Pl@ntNet](https://identify.plantnet.org/), and it says it reckons (about 40% chance) that it's [Carthamus Tinctorius, Safflower](https://identify.plantnet.org/the-plant-list/species/Carthamus%20tinctorius%20L./data).

If it comes out with an orange-yellow flower, you'll know for sure.

Comment: No, that isn't it. I actually have safflowers in my own garden. There is some similarity, but safflower leaves are narrower with a different edge. And the leaves are a bit more grayish in color.

Comment: Yes, they most likely is. Compare to these photos of plants about equal age. https://www.thebetterindia.com/98019/safflower-usefulness-food-cultivation/
I have an explanation of how they came up "spontaneously" along with cannabis: Seeds of both species are relative common in bird seeds. https://www.seabirdsanctuary.org/safflower-seeds/